# How do I calculate the items in a class' property? Swift language

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

A method should calculate the price of all the items in a class’s property. Unfortunately, my knowledge when it comes to programming is ultra limited. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ShoppingItem` model structure should be needed

Comment: @SwiftyCruz hi there, I've added the ShoppingItem class code

Comment: and where define `discount()` and `finalPrice()` in `func print() -> String`

Comment: You appear to have deleted the original code for this question (which is visible in the edits and looks like an assignment task). If you are completing an assignment, try to work out what the underlying problem that needs to be solved is (e.g. accessing the properties of an object using a loop and summing them), and ask questions related to the general problem, rather than asking StackOverflow users to solve the problem for you. See you tutor if you are struggling.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift3

using `reduce`

```
func priceBeforeDiscounts() -> Int {
    return items.reduce(0) { (result, item) in
            return result + item.priceInPence
    }
}
```

using `for in loop`

```
func priceBeforeDiscounts() -> Int {
    var sum: Int = 0
    for item in items {
        sum += item.priceInPence
    }
    return sum
}
```

Comment: or `func priceBeforeDiscounts() -> Int {
    return items.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.priceInPence
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here you have some useful code (prepared in playground) for you:

```
// This is your item class     
    class Item {
            var priceInPence: Int = 0

            init(price: Int) {
                priceInPence = price
            }
        }

    // This is your array of items
        var items = [Item]()

    // Here I create items with given price
        for _ in 0...3 {
            items.append(Item(price: 2))
        }

    // This is the most interesting part for you, here you sum up prices from items in array
        let sum = items.reduce(0, { $0 + $1.priceInPence })

        print(sum)
```

I created this code in playground, so you can copy/past this code to your playground and play with it. Having my example you should be able to update your source code.